# jmeter regex extractor for response header in html

Tags: html, regex, jmeter, html-parsing

I am trying to grab the values from the response header of my login sampler and then use it in the following samplers. However the response header I see is in HTML format as opposed to the colon-separated as most of the other posts have.

Here is my response header:

```
<authentication>
 <token>6e36dcf1f5d84fcc7062b981891dd2b233bd8373d74f56f03a3bf328560976a2</token>
 <anonymous>false</anonymous>
 <parameters> 
   <header> 
     <userName>ps-subscriber2@mysite.com</userName>
     <userType>SUBSCRIPTION_USER</userType>
      <Authorization>6e36dcf1f5d84fcc7062b981891dd2b233bd8373d74f56f03a3bf328560976a2</Authorization>
   </header> 
 </parameters> 
</authentication>
```

I am trying different ways to extract the header values but none seem to be working:

[image: userName]

And here is what i see in the Results Tree when I run the plan:

[image: Result]

I am not well versed with regex which I think is the problem. Can someone help me with getting the regex correct?

Comment: Try `<userName>([^<]*)`.

Comment: Still no go. Same result

Comment: The proposed regex *should* work.  Your regex would need to be updated anyhow to something like `<username>(.*?)<` to prevent it capturing everything after the closing tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It doesn't look like a header to me, it seems like you're testing an API hence I would suggest switching your Regular Expression Extractor to `Body`.
2. JMeter provides [XPath Extractor](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) which is designed to work with XML and XHTML data, consider switching to this test element instead of the Regular Expression Extractor. The relevant configuration will look like:

   - Reference Name: the same as for RegEx, i.e. `userName`
   - XPath query: `//userName`
   - If response is not XML/XHTML-compliant you will need to check `Use Tidy` box
3. You can use [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener which has RegExp Tester and XPath Tester to evaluate your expressions against real response

   [image: XPath Extractor Demo]

References:

- [XPath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Language Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/)

Comment: Thank you Dmitri. Yes I was testing API and the XPATH extractor correctly grabbed all the values I needed.